# Converting SQL query to Spark Dataframe structured data processing

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I want to `convert` the below `query` in `spark dataframe`:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT d.dep_name,count(*) FROM employees e,department d WHERE e.dep_id = d.dep_id GROUP BY d.dep_name HAVING count(*) >= 2").show
```

Output:

```
+---------+---+                                                                 
| dep_name|_c1|
+---------+---+
|  FINANCE|  3|
|    AUDIT|  5|
|MARKETING|  6|
```

I tried it using below query:

```
scala> finalEmployeesDf.as("df1").join(depDf.as("df2"), $"df1.dep_id" === $"df2.dep_id").select($"dep_name").groupBy($"dep_name").count.show()
+---------+-----+                                                               
| dep_name|count|
+---------+-----+
|  FINANCE|    3|
|    AUDIT|    5|
|MARKETING|    6|
+---------+-----+
```

I know that this `isn't correct` coz suppose we have a case where we have only single entry for department then it will be also listed in these results but I want results to be displayed only if `counts are greater than 2`. So how can I achieve this ??? I tried googling but of no help in this case.

Comment: There is no performance difference between the queries and dataframe operation, so why would you need to do this?

Comment: I am just learning from certification perspective @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the group and aggregate parts wrong. You need to select all the relevant columns, group by and aggregate by the relevant once. Here is untested code which will represent the correct approach:

```
finalEmployeesDf.as("df1")
 .join(depDf.as("df2"), $"df1.dep_id" === $"df2.dep_id")
 .select($"dep_name")
 .groupBy($"dep_name")
 .agg(count($"dep_name").as("cnt"))
 .filter($"cnt" > 2)
 .show()
```

A general suggestion is to try and break the API calls into several lines, this makes reading and understanding **much** easier.

Comment: works like a charm. But i had to remove functions before count. What is the significance of that

Comment: @Debuggerr this is ok, count is a function from the `functions` package. It includes many built in functions for processing of dataframes, and count is one of them which is applied after groupBy. you should really take a look on them: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$

Comment: @Debuggerr also please consider accepting/upvoting the answer if it worked and helped you

Comment: But when i tried executing your code it throws an error that functions couldnt be found. I am working on 1.6 version of spark. So do i need to import it explicitly in order to make it working ??

Comment: @Debuggerr for pyspark use `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`, for Scala/Java I always use functions.<function>, but you can use the equivalent `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
DF.groupBy("x").agg(count("*").alias("cnt")).where($"cnt" > 2)
```

Comment: Simple and sweet !